# merging two files delimited with colon

Tags: python

I have two files delimited with colon with following content

- `File1: param1:param2`
- `File2: param2:param3`

I would like to produce `File3: param1:param3` so merge both input files because param2 is common for them.

I wrote two for loops to achieve that but I think it's not going to be efficient enough with larger files.

EDIT: as requested by users, here is a code I wrote with for loops, where file1 and file2 contains literally lines mentioned in description of this post

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

delimiter=':'

file1='file1.txt'
file2='file2.txt'

with open(file1) as file1data:
    f1data = dict(map(str, line.split(delimiter, 1)) for line in file1data if delimiter in line)

with open(file2) as file2data:
    f2data = dict(map(str, line.split(delimiter, 1)) for line in file2data if delimiter in line)

# print('f1data: {}'.format(f1data))
# print('f2data: {}'.format(f2data))

for a in f1data:
    # print('f1data[a]: {}'.format(f1data[a]))
    # print('a: {}'.format(a))
    if f1data[a] in f2data:
        # print('f2data[f1data[a]]: {}'.format(f2data[f1data[a]]))
        print('{}{}{}'.format(a, delimiter, f2data[f1data[a]]))

file1data.close()
file2data.close()
```

Comment: can you show us the code you already have?

Comment: I don't think "merge" is an accurate description of what you want to do.

Comment: You have to read two files line by line. Reading each line in a `for`-loop seems natural to me. You could put the lines into a `dict` for each file: one mapping `param2` to `param1` and one mapping `param2` to `param3`. Then you can iterate over the keys (`param2`) and join `param1` and `param3` with that.

Comment: Sure @JackO'neill, please check out my edited post

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider that there is no single solution for this problem.

As a suggestion, it can be implemented using hashmaps (`dict` in python).

To be more memory efficient, keeping less keys in memory, you can build a dict mapping the shortest file.

By example, let's assume File1 is the shorter.

```
file_1_map = dict()

with open('File1', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        param1, param2 = line.split(':')
        file_1_map[param2] = param1
```

Now, you have a `file_1_map` mapping `param2 -> param1`.

Next, you iterate over the second file, and, for each line, you look for the corresponding `param1` for the giving `param2` of the second file.

```
with open('File2', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        param2, param3 = line.split(':')
        param1 = file_1_map[param2]
        # Here, you can write the output for the target file.
        print(f"{param1}:{param3}")
```